# C prompt being overwritten

Tags: c

I'm new to C and I encountered a weird problem.

This code is part of a bigger program, but the problem is within here but I can't seem to figure it out.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#define WORDSIZE 512

int read_stdNum(const char prompt[], char store[], size_t n) {
    char inHold[WORDSIZE];
    char process[10];
    int status = 0;

    while (1) {
        fprintf(stderr, "%s", prompt);

        if(fgets(inHold, WORDSIZE, stdin) == NULL) {
            return 0;
        }

        sscanf(inHold, "%s", process);

        status = sscanf(process, "%s", store);

        if (status > 0 && strlen(store) == n) {
            return 1;
        } else if (status == -1) {
            continue;
        } else {
            continue;
        }
    }
}

int main(void) {
    char arrow[] = "\n==> ";
    char stdNum[10];

    printf("%s\n", "store_student called.");

    fprintf(stderr, "%s", "\nEnter a student number (axxxxxxxx)\n");
    read_stdNum(arrow, stdNum, 9);
    return 0;
}
```

The program asks for user input, and the test here is for the program to truncate the extra digits, but when I type something like "`a123456789101112131415`", the output is nothing, which works fine, but then the prompt gets over written and the prompt looks like this:

```
==> a123456789101112131415
131415_
```

The underscore is where I can still enter in input.
The the character array 'process' is also storing more than 9 characters.
I've asked some of my classmates, and also one of them said that it worked fine on his computer.
I know I'm going to get flamed for being dumb but I really want to know why this is not working.
Thanks.

Comment: You pass `9` as the length of the string to read, and according to your input you only enter `6` characters. That means that `strlen(store) != n`. Now think about that for a few minutes. Then run your program in a debugger and step through the code line by line to see what's really happening. Hopefully it should give you some clues as to what the problem you have might be.

Comment: Your `sscanf` calls can overflow the buffer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`scanf` function with "`%s`" may be unsafe and create buffer overflow (it may write more bytes into output string than the space allocated for the string, *overwriting* some useful data), check https://cwe.mitre.org/data/definitions/120.html "CWE-120: Buffer Copy without Checking Size of Input ('Classic Buffer Overflow')" & example 1

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Scanf_format_string#Vulnerabilities

> This means that uses of `%s` placeholders without length specifiers are inherently insecure and exploitable for buffer overflows.

Documentation of `scanf` has some requirements about `s` format usage (array **must** be long enough) http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/scanf.3.html

> ```
>  s   
>           Matches a sequence of non-white-space characters; the next
>           pointer must be a pointer to the initial element of a
>           character array that is long enough to hold the input sequence
>           and the terminating null byte ('\0'), which is added
>           automatically.  The input string stops at white space or at
>           the maximum field width, whichever occurs first.
> ```

The safer usage of scanf-like functions is to use "maximum field width" like `%9s` or `m` for dynamic memory allocation.

(Your check with `strlen` is too late; `sscanf` already did the overflow/overwrite of string because it had no limit on length to read.)

Comment: Thank you very much, I figured it out!